# How to fetch data in multiple multidimensional array from mysql using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am working on a report on which all employees and their salary detail will be fetch according to the departments wise. I have successfully fetch the employees by the department using multidimensional array but now I need to fetch the employees_salary_detail on that employees detail multidimensional array. It means first department->emp_detail->salarydetail. I have successfully fetch the first two part but now i am facing issue on fetching the last array in that emp_detail array.

```
public function getDepartmentReport(){
        $employee = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('departments')
                ->where('project_id', $this->session->userdata('client_id'))->get()->result_array();

                $data = array();

        foreach($employee as $m => $v){
       
            $v['emp_detail'] =  $this->db->select('first_name,employee_code,employees_salary.*')
                                         ->from('employees')
                                         ->join('employees_salary', 'employees_salary.employee_id = employees.id')
                                         ->where('employees.department_id',$v['id'])
                                         ->where('employees_salary.month', 'Nov')
                                         ->get()->result_array();
                                         $data[] = $v;         
   

            foreach($v['emp_detail'] as $m => $s){
                $s['salary_detail'] = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('employees_salary_detail')->where('employees_salary_detail.salary_id', $s['id'])
                ->get()->result_array();  
                $data[] = $s;         

            }
            
        }
        return $data;
   }
```

[image]

But now it is creating seperate array for showing salary detail not in that emp_detail array.
I don't know where i am making mistake. please help me to fix this issue.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE FOR HELPING

Answer (score 0):

Use Join Method to join all three tables in the database on the basis of common keys. I can see you have joined two tables same way you can join multiple tables and create a single array of data.

```
$qry = $this->db->query("SELECT  * FROM product_section INNER 
JOIN products ON product_section.ps_prid = products.prid INNER 
JOIN wishlist ON wishlist.wish_product_id = products.product_id 
INNER JOIN customer ON wishlist.wish_user_id = customer.cust_id
INNER JOIN brands ON brands.brand_id = products.product_brand
WHERE customer.cust_id = '$cid' GROUP BY  
product_section.ps_prid");
```

like this above code